# Create new torrent and seed

Tags: python, python-2.7, libtorrent

I'm using the following code to create a new torret and share but something is wrong because never seed.

```
import sys
import time
import libtorrent as lt

#Create torrent
fs = lt.file_storage()
lt.add_files(fs, "./test.txt")
t = lt.create_torrent(fs)
t.add_tracker("udp://tracker.openbittorrent.com:80/announce", 0)
t.set_creator('libtorrent %s' % lt.version)
t.set_comment("Test")
lt.set_piece_hashes(t, ".")
torrent = t.generate()    
f = open("mytorrent.torrent", "wb")
f.write(lt.bencode(torrent))
f.close()

#Seed torrent
ses = lt.session()
ses.listen_on(6881, 6891)
h = ses.add_torrent({'ti': lt.torrent_info('mytorrent.torrent'), 'save_path': '.', 'seed_mode': True}) 
print "Total size: " + str(h.status().total_wanted)
print "Name: " + h.name()   
while True:
    s = h.status()
    state_str = ['queued', 'checking', 'downloading metadata', \
      'downloading', 'finished', 'seeding', 'allocating', 'checking fastresume']

    print('\r%.2f%% complete (down: %.1f kb/s up: %.1f kB/s peers: %d) %s' % \
      (s.progress * 100, s.download_rate / 1000, s.upload_rate / 1000, s.num_peers, state_str[s.state]))
    sys.stdout.flush()

    time.sleep(1)
```

Test in order:

- I run the script
- mytorrent.torrent is created correctly
- print "Total size: " and print "Name:" is OK
- Loop print in order:

100.00% complete (down: 0.0 kb/s up: 0.0 kB/s peers: 0) seeding (8 times)

100.00% complete (down: 0.0 kb/s up: 0.0 kB/s peers: 1) seeding (11 times)(This happens always, even if not run the torrent client.)

100.00% complete (down: 0.0 kb/s up: 0.0 kB/s peers: 0) seeding (infinite times)

- I run torrent file with torrent client and nothing happens.

[image]

- In addition to trying download the torrent with a commercial software 
  as above, I have also tried downloading with libtorrent library. 
  Always shows 0 peers.

Variations in the test with the same results:

- I tried to use different trackers:

  ```
         trackerList = ['udp://tracker.istole.it:80/announce',
             'udp://tracker.ccc.de:80/announce',
             'http://tracker.torrentbay.to:6969/announce',
             'udp://fr33domtracker.h33t.com:3310/announce',
             'udp://tracker.publicbt.com:80/announce',
             'udp://tracker.openbittorrent.com:80/announce',
             'udp://11.rarbg.com/announce'
             'udp://tracker.istole.it:80/announce']

         for tracker in trackerList:        
              t.add_tracker(tracker, 0)
  ```
- I have run the torrent file in client immediately after executing the script and also later.
- lt.torrent_info('mytorrent.torrent') replaced by lt.torrent_info(torrent)

Additional Information:

- For testing I am using two Windows computers, each connected to a different network. 
  In each network, the required ports are open.
- The time that has been running each test is at least 1:20 hrs.

Other tests:

- In the computer I used to share, I tried to share a torrent created by someone else. I have run the code marked with "#Seed torrent" it worked:

  100.00% complete (down: 2.0 kb/s up: 45.0 kB/s peers: 13) seeding
- In the computer that I use to download the torrent I downloaded a torrent (with libtorrent) already created by someone else, and it worked correctly.

Therefore I can only think that there is a problem in "#create torrent" piece of code. As if the tracker will not save the information set.

Comment: Are the ports open in your firewall?

Comment: Yes. I can download any torrent except mine.

Comment: are you trying to download on the same computer as you are seeding? How long have you waited for it to download? If your ports are not open, you have to wait at least one tracker announce interval (which typically is 30-60 minutes)

Comment: I edited the question with the information you ask.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem has been solved using different trackers instead of listed in "trackerList". The code is correct.